# Parsing specific Json Arrays in cpp

Tags: c++, json, glm-math

I'm trying to parse a certain json file which contains attributes of blocks for my openGL prorgram.
it goes like this

```
{
    "data": [
                      //I have highlighted the layout of the data for parsing
                      <--------Vec3------------->  <-----------vec3------------->    <--------vec3-----------> <-float->
        [ "emerald", "0.0215", "0.1745", "0.0215", "0.07568", "0.61424", "0.07568", "0.633", "0.727811", 0.633", "0.6" ],
        [ "jade", "0.135", "0.2225", "0.1575", "0.54", "0.89", "0.63", "0.316228", "0.316228", "0.316228", "0.1" ],
        [ "obsidian", "0.05375", "0.05", "0.06625", "0.18275", "0.17", "0.22525", "0.332741", "0.328634", "0.346435", "0.3" ],
        [ "pearl", "0.25", "0.20725", "0.20725", "1", "0.829", "0.829", "0.296648", "0.296648", "0.296648", "0.088" ],
        [ "ruby", "0.1745", "0.01175", "0.01175", "0.61424", "0.04136", "0.04136", "0.727811", "0.626959", "0.626959", "0.6" ],
        .
        .
        .
```

I also have a class of what I need to store per block, it goes like this::

```
class block_Materials
{
private:
    glm::vec3 ambientStrength;
    glm::vec3 diffusionFactor;
    glm::vec3 specularStrength;
    int shinynessExponent;
}
```

I have no experience with any json library with c++, and I would like to store it as an unordered_map preferably. But any inputs to convert it to an std::vector will also help.

Thanks

Comment: I know the json looks a bit weird , I used a basic python script it scrape it off from an HTML table.

Comment: you have two tasks here : de-serialization and mapping. For de-serialzation you could use [nlohmann json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). Mapping has to be done manually. The format is weird indeed. For the sake of putting the material name on the same level as its values, it forces floating values to be written as strings.

Comment: If you have a complex problem, the solution is often to [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Split up the complex task into smaller and simpler sub-tasks. Continue with this division into sub-tasks until they can't be divided any more. Then do each sub-task one by one, putting them together until you have a finished program which does your original complex task.